# Failed to compile haskell source using GHC, link error

Tags: haskell, compilation, linker, ghc, archlinux

I'm new to Haskell. with GHC, I tried to compile:

trace.hs, a simple ray tracer (content may doesn't matter):

```
import System.IO
import System.Process
import Linear.V3
import Linear.Metric
import Linear.Vector
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

type Scalar = Double
type Vector = V3 Scalar
type Distance = Scalar
type Position = Vector
type Direction = Vector
type Arrow = Vector
type Color = Vector
data Ray = Ray Position Direction


trace :: Ray -> Color
trace (Ray origin direction) = direction

colorToInt x = round $ 255 * sqrt x

main = do
  let image = "image.ppm"
      (nx, ny) = (40, 40)
      eyepos = V3 0 0 0
      genRay dir = Ray eyepos $ normalize dir
      rayGen sx sy = genRay $ V3 sx sy 1
      rayOf x y = let fi = fromIntegral in
                      rayGen (fi x / fi nx + 0.5)
                             (fi y / fi ny + 0.5)
      rays = rayOf <$> [0..nx-1] <*> [0..ny-1]
      result = map (fmap colorToInt) . map trace $ rays

  handle <- openFile image WriteMode
  let put = hPutStrLn handle

  put "P3"
  put $ show nx ++ ' ' : show ny
  put "255"

  forM_ result $ \(V3 r g b) -> do
    put $ show r ++ ' ' : show g ++ ' ' : show b

  hClose handle
  system $ "display " ++ image
  return ()
```

**but error occurred**:

```
bate@archbin:~/hsrt/vuee$ ghc --make trace.hs
Linking trace ...
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSlens-4.15.4-L23zn92GAPI1hUmidWzY63
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSvector-0.12.0.1-692PQMDMB6pIQ1uGwefDcQ
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSth-abstraction-0.2.5.0-IQJC3onXzKuCarhyL6pEOQ
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSreflection-2.1.2-1Oix9U9tVVU4sCEhxeh8Kr
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSparallel-3.2.1.1-KQJHWCcq2Ka569Stb10nhx

...

/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSStateVar-1.1.0.4-8WOljMLP9CI2EkNoKyIopY
/usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find -lHSstm-2.4.4.1-iSYwp3RMY11sHCifJ3gtR
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
bate@archbin:~/hsrt/vuee$ 
bate@archbin:~/hsrt/vuee$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.0.2
bate@archbin:~/hsrt/vuee$ 
bate@archbin:~/hsrt/vuee$ ls /usr/lib/libHS*
/usr/lib/libHSadjunctions-4.3-IiXaMJ9VhRwGggTqHGtSLU-ghc8.0.2.so
/usr/lib/libHSaeson-1.1.2.0-8R262j8BseM7FTnCfGfbwu-ghc8.0.2.so
/usr/lib/libHSaeson-compat-0.3.7.1-BegDnMRPSO7KSvclD5A4Lc-ghc8.0.2.so
/usr/lib/libHSansi-wl-pprint-0.6.8-442hsaqSoAVL7JUQ0ogC39-ghc8.0.2.so

...
```

I'm on Arch Linux, i686, with package ghc, ghc-static installed.

The error occur since I've reinstalled GHC using
`sudo pacman -S ghc ghc-static`

the error seems to be caused by Linear.*

I've tried remove /usr/local/bin $PATH, but nothing well.

In /usr/lib, I found libHS*ghc-8.0.2.so.
It seems ghc didn't tell ld to -lHS*ghc-8.0.2, why?

How should I fix this?

Comment: it passed using GHCi.

Comment: the content of trace.hs seems doesn't matter at all.

Comment: It failed to compile just today.

Comment: the reinstallation was succeed.

Comment: reinstall with no new updates.

Comment: Link errors on arch are not uncommon iirc, there is something broken about the way arch is packaging Haskell libraries.  I think [this bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/54561) is related.